# The Exe file that was build with python installer does not work now

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I was build one exe file with python installer.
The code is using numpy package and pyqt UI builder.
I installed numpy in virtulal environment of my working folder.
It is working in python script, then I build it as Exe file, then it is not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMpAA.png)

please help me if you know about the issue.
Thanks

Comment: There are many things that potentially could have gone wrong here, but we can't do the guesswork for you without any additional information. Please read this: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html.

Comment: Try uninstalling NumPy and re-installing it again

Comment: As @jfaccioni mentioned, I guess you should read about [hidden imports](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports) on that section.

Answer (score 0):

While using pyinstaller to convert .py file to .exe having large dependencies (like numpy, pandas) following these steps would solve the ModuleNotFound error:

1. Install the PIP packages in the project directory **(with virtual environment activated)**
2. Change the hook file
   Navigate to \venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks
   If there is a hook-numpy.py file, edit the script to:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('numpy._libs')
```

3. Before converting to .exe file, make .spec file using the following command:

```
pyi-makespec — onefile program_name.py
```

4. Edit the .spec file (open using notepad)
   append the libraries to the hiddenimports list

```
...
hiddenimports = ['numpy']
...
```

5. Compile the script using the .spec file with the following command:

```
pyinstaller — onefile program_name.spec
```

Finally, find the .exe file in the dist folder, and run it.